# Consolidating a raw csv of two ids to grouped set of ids in json

Tags: ruby, json, csv

The file I'm processing here is an outputted file from a Java library called [duke](https://github.com/larsga/Duke).

Its goal was go through all purchases made on a site and group them into a single customer. The output is a csv file in the format, you'll find an example of it below the code.

I want to know if I've written this in a readable way or if there are any problems with the way I've written it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'thor'
require 'csv'
require 'json'

# This is the class we use to extend and use thor
class DukeFileProcessor < Thor
  desc 'dedupe <FILE>', 'Will process a file generated by Duke.'

  # Thor dedupe command
  #
  # @param csv_file_path [String]
  #
  # @return File
  def dedupe(csv_file_path)
    unmerged_ids = parse_csv(csv_file_path)
    merged_ids   = merge_ids(unmerged_ids)

    File.open(csv_file_path + '.matches.json', 'w').write(merged_ids.to_json)
  end

  private

  # Merges the unmerged ids so they are all consolidated under a single
  # group that we can call a customer
  #
  # Process:
  #   - Iterate through all unmerged_ids
  #     - Assign the current value of what's being iterated over to matches
  #     - Iterate through the current value to find matches in unmerged_ids
  #         and then merge matches into the current matches
  #     - Finally add the current key and matches to the merged_ids variable
  #
  # @param unmerged_ids [Array]
  #
  # @return File
  def merge_ids(unmerged_ids)
    merged_ids = {}

    unmerged_ids.each_pair do |key, value|
      value.each do |match_id|
        next if unmerged_ids[match_id].nil?

        unmerged_ids[match_id].each do |policy_id|
          value.push(policy_id) unless value.include?(policy_id)
        end
      end

      merged_ids[key] = value - [key]
    end
  end

  # Parses the given file and does a simple merge on ids to create
  # an array of all secondary_ids that match the primary_id
  #
  # CSV Format: (is_match?(-/+),target,match,probability)
  #
  # @param csv_file_path [String]
  #
  # @return Hash
  def parse_csv(csv_file_path)
    unmerged_ids = {}

    CSV.foreach(csv_file_path) do |row|
      primary_id   = row[1].to_i
      secondary_id = row[2].to_i

      unmerged_ids[primary_id] = [] if unmerged_ids[primary_id].nil?
      unmerged_ids[primary_id].push(secondary_id)
    end

    unmerged_ids
  end
end

DukeFileProcessor.start
```

Here's the first 500 lines from the file I'm using. The format of which is:

> `is_match?(-/+),target,match,probability`
>
> ```
> +,6,7,0.9997260166738423
> +,3,4,0.9997260166738423
> +,8,9,0.9997260166738423
> +,9,8,0.9997260166738423
> +,7,6,0.9997260166738423
> +,6,10,0.9997260166738423
> +,4,3,0.9997260166738423
> +,10,6,0.9997260166738423
> +,8,296,0.9986244841815681
> +,6,39,0.9983391066412223
> +,8,299,0.9986244841815681
> +,7,10,0.9997260166738423
> +,6,40,0.9983391066412223
> +,9,296,0.9986244841815681
> +,8,1101,0.9986244841815681
> +,10,7,0.9997260166738423
> +,6,1081,0.9983391066412223
> +,6,1083,0.9983391066412223
> +,10,39,0.9983391066412223
> +,10,40,0.9983391066412223
> +,10,1081,0.9983391066412223
> +,10,1083,0.9983391066412223
> +,8,1125,0.9997260166738423
> +,8,1128,0.9997260166738423
> +,9,299,0.9986244841815681
> +,8,1132,0.9997260166738423
> +,9,1101,0.9986244841815681
> +,9,1125,0.9997260166738423
> +,9,1128,0.9997260166738423
> +,7,39,0.9983391066412223
> +,8,1144,0.9986244841815681
> +,8,1149,0.9986244841815681
> +,7,40,0.9983391066412223
> +,9,1132,0.9997260166738423
> +,7,1081,0.9983391066412223
> +,7,1083,0.9983391066412223
> +,9,1144,0.9986244841815681
> +,9,1149,0.9986244841815681
> +,12,24781,0.9997260166738423
> +,11,16,0.9999872532595235
> +,17,15,0.9997260166738423
> +,16,11,0.9999872532595235
> +,7,36,0.9977532413823246
> +,6,36,0.9977532413823246
> +,10,36,0.9977532413823246
> +,15,17,0.9997260166738423
> +,18,560,0.99892382632337
> +,59,56,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,36,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,1333,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,1341,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,12479,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,19462,0.9997260166738423
> +,37,19466,0.9997260166738423
> +,70,64,0.9997260166738423
> +,70,106,0.9997260166738423
> +,27,8200,0.9999217037269025
> +,28,397,0.9981390956560382
> +,27,8229,0.9999217037269025
> +,49,145,0.9991644138608996
> +,49,19596,0.9998336350736409
> +,49,250925,0.9991644138608996
> +,64,70,0.9997260166738423
> +,64,106,0.9997260166738423
> +,26,22,0.9999217037269025
> +,27,66061,0.9990737249986892
> +,27,69613,0.9990737249986892
> +,27,69617,0.9990737249986892
> +,27,70011,0.9990737249986892
> +,23,613,0.9999217037269025
> +,27,70885,0.999849094020817
> +,23,1186,0.9999217037269025
> +,77,87,0.9997260166738423
> +,23,1274,0.9999217037269025
> +,22,26,0.9999217037269025
> +,23,7603,0.9999217037269025
> +,27,70946,0.9990737249986892
> +,23,7759,0.9996066089693157
> +,23,7766,0.9996066089693157
> +,95,100,0.9997260166738423
> +,95,12510,0.9997260166738423
> +,23,12437,0.9996066089693157
> +,23,12455,0.9996066089693157
> +,23,32083,0.9999217037269025
> +,39,40,0.9997260166738423
> +,39,1081,0.9997260166738423
> +,40,39,0.9997260166738423
> +,39,1083,0.9997260166738423
> +,40,1081,0.9997260166738423
> +,40,1083,0.9997260166738423
> +,39,36,0.9996291897994778
> +,39,37,0.9996291897994778
> +,40,36,0.9996291897994778
> +,39,1333,0.9996291897994778
> +,40,37,0.9996291897994778
> +,39,1341,0.9996291897994778
> +,40,1333,0.9996291897994778
> +,39,1352,0.9997851370603088
> +,114,108,0.9997260166738423
> +,40,1341,0.9996291897994778
> +,40,1352,0.9997851370603088
> +,46,48,0.9997260166738423
> +,56,59,0.9997260166738423
> +,126,123,0.9997260166738423
> +,126,131,0.9997260166738423
> +,126,132,0.9997260166738423
> +,88,65,0.9997260166738423
> +,87,77,0.9997260166738423
> +,36,37,0.9997260166738423
> +,36,1333,0.9997260166738423
> +,36,1341,0.9997260166738423
> +,150,148,0.9997260166738423
> +,150,155,0.9997260166738423
> +,36,12479,0.9997260166738423
> +,36,19462,0.9997260166738423
> +,36,19466,0.9997260166738423
> +,162,153,0.9997260166738423
> +,72,61,0.9999217037269025
> +,72,8079,0.9999217037269025
> +,65,88,0.9997260166738423
> +,48,46,0.9997260166738423
> +,100,95,0.9997260166738423
> +,100,12510,0.9997260166738423
> +,84,190,0.9997260166738423
> +,189,223,0.9997878432419376
> +,108,114,0.9997260166738423
> +,104,24385,0.9997260166738423
> +,104,24389,0.9997260166738423
> +,90,89,0.9998336350736409
> +,97,10059,0.9999478011222758
> +,89,90,0.9998336350736409
> +,61,72,0.9999217037269025
> +,61,8079,0.9999217037269025
> +,131,123,0.9997260166738423
> +,103,110,0.9997260166738423
> +,74,19142,0.9999217037269025
> +,131,126,0.9997260166738423
> +,131,132,0.9997260166738423
> +,208,18729,0.998739204342771
> +,148,150,0.9997260166738423
> +,148,155,0.9997260166738423
> +,106,64,0.9997260166738423
> +,106,70,0.9997260166738423
> +,161,159,0.9997260166738423
> +,123,126,0.9997260166738423
> +,123,131,0.9997260166738423
> +,123,132,0.9997260166738423
> +,169,166,0.9997260166738423
> +,110,103,0.9997260166738423
> +,139,164,0.9998336350736409
> +,139,4468,0.9998336350736409
> +,240,248,0.9997260166738423
> +,153,162,0.9997260166738423
> +,132,123,0.9997260166738423
> +,132,126,0.9997260166738423
> +,132,131,0.9997260166738423
> +,254,1263,0.9999217037269025
> +,107,6,0.9878882293158856
> +,107,7,0.9878882293158856
> +,107,10,0.9878882293158856
> +,181,177,0.9997260166738423
> +,145,49,0.9991644138608996
> +,181,191,0.9997260166738423
> +,156,146,0.9997260166738423
> +,181,236,0.9986244841815681
> +,156,230,0.9997260166738423
> +,107,39,0.9878882293158856
> +,181,657,0.9986244841815681
> +,145,19596,0.9991644138608996
> +,155,148,0.9997260166738423
> +,107,40,0.9878882293158856
> +,181,675,0.9986244841815681
> +,145,250925,0.9998336350736409
> +,181,912,0.9997260166738423
> +,155,150,0.9997260166738423
> +,107,1081,0.9878882293158856
> +,124,217,0.9997260166738423
> +,156,278,0.9997260166738423
> +,190,84,0.9997260166738423
> +,107,1083,0.9878882293158856
> +,166,169,0.9997260166738423
> +,107,36,0.9836761877555505
> +,159,161,0.9997260166738423
> +,199,219,0.9997260166738423
> +,167,174,0.9997260166738423
> +,193,2934,0.9997260166738423
> +,193,2998,0.9997260166738423
> +,193,3366,0.9997260166738423
> +,204,214,0.9997260166738423
> +,177,181,0.9997260166738423
> +,177,191,0.9997260166738423
> +,278,146,0.9997260166738423
> +,207,213,0.9999217037269025
> +,214,204,0.9997260166738423
> +,278,156,0.9997260166738423
> +,177,236,0.9986244841815681
> +,278,230,0.9997260166738423
> +,223,189,0.9997878432419376
> +,146,156,0.9997260166738423
> +,146,230,0.9997260166738423
> +,146,278,0.9997260166738423
> +,209,3572,0.9997260166738423
> +,236,177,0.9986244841815681
> +,236,181,0.9986244841815681
> +,236,191,0.9986244841815681
> +,236,657,0.9997260166738423
> +,236,675,0.9997260166738423
> +,177,657,0.9986244841815681
> +,207,21998,0.9999217037269025
> +,236,912,0.9986244841815681
> +,177,675,0.9986244841815681
> +,177,912,0.9997260166738423
> +,298,300,0.9997260166738423
> +,245,244,0.9997260166738423
> +,298,307,0.9997260166738423
> +,213,207,0.9999217037269025
> +,213,21998,0.9999217037269025
> +,306,304,0.9997260166738423
> +,164,139,0.9998336350736409
> +,164,4468,0.9998336350736409
> +,217,124,0.9997260166738423
> +,160,7682,0.9998890838982443
> +,160,7725,0.9998890838982443
> +,160,7735,0.9998890838982443
> +,160,66236,0.9998890838982443
> +,160,69756,0.9998890838982443
> +,174,167,0.9997260166738423
> +,244,245,0.9997260166738423
> +,219,199,0.9997260166738423
> +,333,1259,0.9997260166738423
> +,182,1530,0.9999729135649095
> +,260,802,0.9986244841815681
> +,226,216,0.9998336350736409
> +,226,1089,0.9998336350736409
> +,226,1090,0.9998336350736409
> +,226,1092,0.9998336350736409
> +,226,1093,0.9998336350736409
> +,226,1094,0.9998336350736409
> +,226,1095,0.9998336350736409
> +,226,1096,0.9998336350736409
> +,196,200,0.9997260166738423
> +,272,285,0.9997260166738423
> +,272,290,0.9997260166738423
> +,191,177,0.9997260166738423
> +,191,181,0.9997260166738423
> +,191,236,0.9986244841815681
> +,191,657,0.9986244841815681
> +,191,675,0.9986244841815681
> +,191,912,0.9997260166738423
> +,206,405,0.9997260166738423
> +,343,352,0.9997260166738423
> +,200,196,0.9997260166738423
> +,352,343,0.9997260166738423
> +,216,226,0.9998336350736409
> +,230,146,0.9997260166738423
> +,216,1089,0.9998336350736409
> +,230,156,0.9997260166738423
> +,230,278,0.9997260166738423
> +,361,350,0.9997260166738423
> +,361,360,0.9997260166738423
> +,310,313,0.9997260166738423
> +,216,1090,0.9998336350736409
> +,216,1092,0.9998336350736409
> +,241,238,0.9997260166738423
> +,216,1093,0.9998336350736409
> +,216,1094,0.9998336350736409
> +,216,1095,0.9998336350736409
> +,216,1096,0.9998336350736409
> +,319,344,0.9997260166738423
> +,249,263,0.9997260166738423
> +,328,322,0.9997260166738423
> +,328,335,0.9997260166738423
> +,328,1299,0.9997260166738423
> +,328,9497,0.9997260166738423
> +,225,215,0.9998336350736409
> +,238,241,0.9997260166738423
> +,220,237,0.9999478011222758
> +,248,240,0.9997260166738423
> +,347,345,0.9997260166738423
> +,357,353,0.9997260166738423
> +,309,369,0.9997260166738423
> +,215,225,0.9998336350736409
> +,367,368,0.9997260166738423
> +,384,373,0.9997260166738423
> +,269,291,0.9997260166738423
> +,269,294,0.9997260166738423
> +,269,1272,0.9997260166738423
> +,269,12493,0.9997260166738423
> +,269,12494,0.9997260166738423
> +,269,12495,0.9997260166738423
> +,269,12496,0.9997260166738423
> +,269,12498,0.9997260166738423
> +,269,12499,0.9997260166738423
> +,403,12841,0.9997260166738423
> +,390,433,0.9997260166738423
> +,403,12876,0.9997260166738423
> +,285,272,0.9997260166738423
> +,285,290,0.9997260166738423
> +,296,8,0.9986244841815681
> +,296,9,0.9986244841815681
> +,296,299,0.9997260166738423
> +,296,1101,0.9997260166738423
> +,296,1125,0.9986244841815681
> +,296,1128,0.9986244841815681
> +,296,1132,0.9986244841815681
> +,291,269,0.9997260166738423
> +,296,1144,0.9997260166738423
> +,291,294,0.9997260166738423
> +,291,1272,0.9997260166738423
> +,291,12493,0.9997260166738423
> +,291,12494,0.9997260166738423
> +,291,12495,0.9997260166738423
> +,291,12496,0.9997260166738423
> +,291,12498,0.9997260166738423
> +,291,12499,0.9997260166738423
> +,296,1149,0.9997260166738423
> +,237,220,0.9999478011222758
> +,417,8102,0.9998336350736409
> +,304,306,0.9997260166738423
> +,300,298,0.9997260166738423
> +,290,272,0.9997260166738423
> +,449,450,0.9997260166738423
> +,300,307,0.9997260166738423
> +,449,459,0.999071786152359
> +,290,285,0.9997260166738423
> +,426,382,0.9999217037269025
> +,426,416,0.9999217037269025
> +,426,480,0.9999217037269025
> +,426,482,0.9999217037269025
> +,426,485,0.9999217037269025
> +,426,486,0.9999217037269025
> +,426,489,0.9999217037269025
> +,426,490,0.9999217037269025
> +,426,492,0.9999217037269025
> +,263,249,0.9997260166738423
> +,436,400,0.9986244841815681
> +,445,600,0.9999217037269025
> +,454,439,0.9997260166738423
> +,454,442,0.9997260166738423
> +,458,452,0.9997260166738423
> +,374,387,0.9997260166738423
> +,299,8,0.9986244841815681
> +,299,9,0.9986244841815681
> +,299,296,0.9997260166738423
> +,299,1101,0.9997260166738423
> +,274,284,0.9997260166738423
> +,299,1125,0.9986244841815681
> +,299,1128,0.9986244841815681
> +,299,1132,0.9986244841815681
> +,299,1144,0.9997260166738423
> +,299,1149,0.9997260166738423
> +,307,298,0.9997260166738423
> +,307,300,0.9997260166738423
> +,322,328,0.9997260166738423
> +,322,335,0.9997260166738423
> +,322,1299,0.9997260166738423
> +,322,9497,0.9997260166738423
> +,476,470,0.9997260166738423
> +,476,471,0.9997260166738423
> +,284,274,0.9997260166738423
> +,313,310,0.9997260166738423
> +,485,382,0.9999217037269025
> +,485,416,0.9999217037269025
> +,485,426,0.9999217037269025
> +,485,480,0.9999217037269025
> +,485,482,0.9999217037269025
> +,485,486,0.9999217037269025
> +,485,489,0.9999217037269025
> +,485,490,0.9999217037269025
> +,485,492,0.9999217037269025
> +,330,334,0.9997260166738423
> +,387,374,0.9997260166738423
> +,316,320,0.9999729135649095
> +,480,382,0.9999217037269025
> +,350,360,0.9997260166738423
> +,493,382,0.9999217037269025
> +,350,361,0.9997260166738423
> +,480,416,0.9999217037269025
> +,493,416,0.9999217037269025
> +,397,28,0.9981390956560382
> +,480,426,0.9999217037269025
> +,480,482,0.9999217037269025
> +,480,485,0.9999217037269025
> +,294,269,0.9997260166738423
> +,480,486,0.9999217037269025
> +,294,291,0.9997260166738423
> +,480,489,0.9999217037269025
> +,359,1064,0.9998890838982443
> +,294,1272,0.9997260166738423
> +,480,490,0.9999217037269025
> +,294,12493,0.9997260166738423
> +,480,492,0.9999217037269025
> +,294,12494,0.9997260166738423
> +,294,12495,0.9997260166738423
> +,369,309,0.9997260166738423
> +,294,12496,0.9997260166738423
> +,294,12498,0.9997260166738423
> +,294,12499,0.9997260166738423
> +,334,330,0.9997260166738423
> +,380,391,0.9997260166738423
> +,380,404,0.9986244841815681
> +,380,410,0.9986244841815681
> +,380,411,0.9986244841815681
> +,351,9570,0.9997260166738423
> +,351,18765,0.9997260166738423
> +,351,18820,0.9997260166738423
> +,351,64976,0.9997260166738423
> +,489,382,0.9999217037269025
> +,489,416,0.9999217037269025
> +,416,382,0.9999217037269025
> +,489,426,0.9999217037269025
> +,344,319,0.9997260166738423
> +,416,426,0.9999217037269025
> +,489,480,0.9999217037269025
> +,416,480,0.9999217037269025
> +,489,482,0.9999217037269025
> +,416,482,0.9999217037269025
> +,489,485,0.9999217037269025
> +,416,485,0.9999217037269025
> +,489,486,0.9999217037269025
> +,416,486,0.9999217037269025
> +,489,490,0.9999217037269025
> +,416,489,0.9999217037269025
> +,416,490,0.9999217037269025
> +,489,492,0.9999217037269025
> +,416,492,0.9999217037269025
> +,410,380,0.9986244841815681
> +,353,357,0.9997260166738423
> +,410,391,0.9986244841815681
> +,360,350,0.9997260166738423
> +,410,404,0.9997260166738423
> +,410,411,0.9997260166738423
> +,497,504,0.9997260166738423
> +,419,427,0.9981390956560382
> +,438,453,0.9997260166738423
> +,438,435,0.9997363863461571
> +,360,361,0.9997260166738423
> +,326,348,0.9997260166738423
> +,435,438,0.9997363863461571
> +,524,533,0.9997260166738423
> +,493,426,0.9999217037269025
> +,435,453,0.9997363863461571
> +,524,924,0.9997260166738423
> +,493,480,0.9999217037269025
> +,326,335704,0.9997260166738423
> +,524,5542,0.9997512856021227
> +,493,482,0.9999217037269025
> +,326,335732,0.9997260166738423
> +,524,5612,0.9997512856021227
> +,493,485,0.9999217037269025
> +,493,486,0.9999217037269025
> +,524,5652,0.9997512856021227
> +,493,489,0.9999217037269025
> +,524,5691,0.9997512856021227
> +,493,490,0.9999217037269025
> +,493,492,0.9999217037269025
> +,524,7343,0.9997512856021227
> +,524,7345,0.9997512856021227
> +,524,7346,0.9997512856021227
> +,456,466,0.9999217037269025
> +,466,456,0.9999217037269025
> +,335,322,0.9997260166738423
> +,509,508,0.9997260166738423
> +,335,328,0.9997260166738423
> +,335,1299,0.9997260166738423
> +,335,9497,0.9997260166738423
> +,453,438,0.9997260166738423
> +,483,496,0.9997260166738423
> +,483,521,0.9997260166738423
> +,483,815,0.9997260166738423
> +,320,316,0.9999729135649095
> +,453,435,0.9997363863461571
> +,382,416,0.9999217037269025
> +,382,426,0.9999217037269025
> +,382,480,0.9999217037269025
> +,382,482,0.9999217037269025
> +,382,485,0.9999217037269025
> +,382,486,0.9999217037269025
> +,382,489,0.9999217037269025
> +,382,490,0.9999217037269025
> +,544,539,0.9997260166738423
> +,382,492,0.9999217037269025
> +,544,541,0.9997260166738423
> +,345,347,0.9997260166738423
> +,553,551,0.9997260166738423
> +,471,470,0.9997260166738423
> +,471,476,0.9997260166738423
> +,561,76267,0.9997260166738423
> +,404,380,0.9986244841815681
> +,404,391,0.9986244841815681
> +,348,326,0.9997260166738423
> +,404,410,0.9997260166738423
> +,348,335704,0.9997260166738423
> +,404,411,0.9997260166738423
> +,348,335732,0.9997260166738423
> +,565,566,0.9997260166738423
> +,534,537,0.9997260166738423
> +,534,538,0.9997260166738423
> +,542,855,0.9997260166738423
> +,542,349839,0.9997260166738423
> ```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, it's better to use string interpolation instead of adding strings together. So I'd replace `csv_file_path + '.matches.json'` with `"#{csv_file_path}.matches.json"`.

Also, `unmerged_ids[primary_id] = [] if unmerged_ids[primary_id].nil?` can be replaced with `unmerged_ids[primary_id] ||= []`. That will assign `unmerged_ids[primary_id]` to `[]` only if `unmerged_ids[primary_id]` is false or nil. There's a good question on it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995593/what-does-or-equals-mean-in-ruby).

And one last thing is that this:

```
primary_id   = row[1].to_i
secondary_id = row[2].to_i
```

could be replaced with `primary_id, secondary_id = row[1, 2].map &:to_i`. There's also a good stackoverflow question on that syntax [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ampersand-colon-shortcut).